# UIActivityViewController initWithActivityItems size

Tags: ios

I have tried to use an array containing only one NSData object which size is over 5 Mo with *initWithActivityItems*

When the completion handler is called :

[_activityViewController -setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError * error),

returnedItems is nil

I don't have this issue when NSData is around 2 Mo

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You're probably just hitting a memory size limit. You can try using a UIActivityItemProvider, but in my understanding this handles the situation where the data are *time-consuming* to provide, not where the data are overly *large*.

Comment: I have implemented UIActivityItemProvider and it works fine on the simulator but still don't on iPad. I continue seaching...
Thanks for help Matt.